# Using Barbies' AllBF in an instance head without UndecidableInstances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-kinds, undecidable-instances

I'd like to use [`AllBF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.2.0/docs/Barbies-Constraints.html#t:AllBF) from [`barbies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies) in an instance head, like so:

```
import Barbies
import Barbies.Constraints

class MyClass a where

instance (ConstraintsB b, AllBF MyClass f b) => MyClass (Barbie b f) where
```

This fails because of a hidden kind-polymorphism. [Simon says](https://twitter.com/kmett/status/1194329413300547587):

> • Variable `k` occurs more often
> in the constraint `AllBF MyClass f b`
> than in the instance head `MyClass (Barbie b f)`   (Use `UndecidableInstances` to permit this)

I'd like to avoid `UndecidableInstances` here. One thing I've tried is making my instance monomorphic in the kind of `f`:

```
instance (ConstraintsB b, AllBF MyClass (f :: Type -> Type) b) => MyClass (Barbie b f) where
```

However, this then results in a different error:

> • Illegal nested constraint `AllBF MyClass f b`   (Use
> `UndecidableInstances` to permit this)

Naively, I tried inlining the definition of `AllBF`, but that doesn't change anything:

```
instance (ConstraintsB b, AllB (ClassF MyClass (f :: Type -> Type)) b) => MyClass (Barbie b f) where
```

> • Illegal nested constraint `AllB (ClassF MyClass f) b`   (Use
> `UndecidableInstances` to permit this)

Is there a way to create this instance without turning on `UndecidableInstances`?

Comment: Why not turn on undecidable instances? Just let the undecidability flow through you.